# Перезапись всех значений ключа HashMap<String, Object> на значение последнего положенного

Tags: java, map, java-hashmap, hashmap

[image: Main class]

[image: Obj class]

Перезапись всех значений ключа HashMap на значение последнего положенного.
Почему так происходит, и как это исправить?

Comment: Код картинкой? `private static int` ?

Comment: @tym32167 да, не обратил внимания на повторяющееся число(сжечь после прочтения)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде есть ошибка. Вы используете статическое поле для записи значения в классе `Obj`. Статическое поле хранит одно и тоже значение для всех объектов данного класса, более того к нему можно обратиться без создания объекта класса.

Чтобы работало так, как вы хотите, нужно убрать static.